# Angular interpolation is altering parent form element, how can I overwrite this function so that ONLY the expression at the text node is evaluated?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, templates, angularjs

I'm working on an eCommerce site and using angular to build a widget on product detail pages. I have very limited control over what is initially rendered as HTML for the browser. Most of what needs to be done with my widget is working as expected. I have a side effect of Angular's expression interpolation affecting the `add to cart` form. Each of a product's color variations will render to the page as as `HTMLOptionElement` with an `innerText` value like one of the following:

`{{hex="000000";sizes=["S","M","L","XL","2XL"];name="Black";}}` or
 
`{{hex="FFFFFF";sizes=["S","M","L"];name="White";}}` or
 
`{{hex="323C88";sizes=["S","M","L","XL","2XL"];name="Royal";}}`

The end result of the Angular initialization process is that each of these is transformed into the following:

`Black` or
`White` or
`Royal` respectively

This is fine, as this allows the user a readable value for his color selection. The side effect is that the parent `HTMLFormElement` no longer submits via the submit button. Its class attribute has been changed to include `ng-pristine` and `ng-valid`.

**Please note I cannot change the HTML of this form until after the page loads.**

I'm sure I could hack together a simple override to get the form to submit, but I'm looking more for information about plugging into angular's initialization. The best I've been able to come up with so far is to wrap the form with `ng-non-bindable` in the java template:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>${MyAddToCartFormRendersHere}</div>
```

But then I'd need a way to do the `$interpolate` call myself after the page had loaded.

**This works but I'll bet there is a better way.**

```
AngularApp.directive("customInterpolation", function ($interpolate, $document) {
$document.find("option:contains('{{')").each(function(i,el){
    var angEl = angular.element(el);
    angEl.text($interpolate(angEl.text(),true));
});
```

and then the form wrapper becomes:

```
<div ng-non-bindable data-custom-interpolation>${MyAddToCartFormRendersHere}</div>
```

My directive will run once, but returning anything (e.g. a link function) is useless because of the nonBindable directive.
... there has to be a better way.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWecG/3/) to better illustrate the issue. Note, the form won't submit unless the `ngNonBindable` directive is applied to the surrounding `<div>`.

Comment: `<div class="ng-non-bindable">` surely?

Comment: I didn't really follow all of that. How about a Plunker or jsFiddle?

Comment: Why would changing the class causing the form not to submit anymore?

Comment: When angular finds a `form` directive without a value for its action attribute it calls `preventDefault` on the submit event. At that point it becomes an 'angular' form. That is by design as usually angular is meant for single page apps, and an element that triggers a full page reload goes against the grain. I need to re-enable the submit (possibly after an action is set) in a non-hacky way, or prevent the form directive from compiling in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a directive with a compile function that finds the `form` and modifies the `action` attribute to include a `?`.  The directive's compile function will execute before Angular compiles the form.

HTML:

```
<div modify-action>
  <form class="product-border product-gap addtocart" method="post" action="">
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('modifyAction', function() {
    return {
        compile: function(element) {
            var form = element.find('form');
            console.log(form);
            form.attr('action', '?');
            console.log(form);
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/J2uLy/).  When you hit submit, you'll see that the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you, this will work. My only hesitation is placing the wrapper at some arbitrary ancestor of the form. With my crumby CMS this form element could be included many times, potentially in many different nestings. Could I just overwrite the empty action attribute as its own directive, and then run your compile function template manipulation?

Comment: @bodine, sorry, I'm not following this: "Could I just overwrite the empty action attribute as its own directive, and then run your compile function template manipulation?"  Can you provide an example of what you'd like to do?